# If one string in column is equal, print specific text wit AWK

Tags: awk, find, equality

I have problem, could you help me pls?

INPUT:

```
LIS
LOP
LOP
LAT
```

If one or more string in input will be "LIS" print one row "THERE IS LIS" if There will be combination of "LOP" or "LAT", without "LIS", print "THERE IS LOP" and if there will be all strings "LAT" print "THERE IS ONLY LAT".
Thank you

Comment: Did you try anything yourself?

Comment: Yes I tried it to do in more rows: I tried to print rows only with LIS and if there is more rows than 0 i print THERE IS LIS and same for other condition, but it is not in one awk

Comment: awk '{if($1=="LIS") print $0}' | awk 'END{if (NR>0) print "THERE IS LIS"}' and so on.. But I do not know how to put it under one awk ...

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input (include all of the cases you described and more) plus the expected output given that input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***awk*** solution:

**check_column.awk** script:

```
#!/bin/awk -f

/LIS/{ print "THERE IS LIS"; exit }
$0!~/(LOP|LAT)/{ print "No matches"; exit }
/LOP/{ lop++ }/LAT/{ lat++ }
END{ 
    if (lop || lat) { 
        printf "%s\n", (lat==NR)? "THERE IS ONLY LAT":"THERE IS LOP" 
    } 
}
```

---

***Usage:***

Sample file `file1`:

```
LIS
LOP
LOP
LAT
```

---

```
awk -f check_column.awk file1
THERE IS LIS
```

**----------**

Sample file `file2`:

```
LOP
LOP
LAT
LAT
```

---

```
awk -f check_column.awk file2
THERE IS LOP
```

**----------**

Sample file `file3`:

```
LAT
LAT
LAT
```

---

```
awk -f check_column.awk file3
THERE IS ONLY LAT
```